# Trying to parse a logfile and get stateinformation

Tags: vb.net, parsing, logging, text-files

I try to program some logfile Report with vb.net

I have a Textfile that gives something like this. First Line is the date of the second line Happening. The Letter represents for example a username and the number a state which this user is in. (license check in / check out). 3rd line is some message which can not be ignored

The solution should show me which Letters are in State "1"

## #

01.02.2017

A 1

some Message

02.03.2017

B 0

some Message

02.03.2017

C 1

some Message

12.06.2017

D 1

some Message

12.06.2017

A 0

some Message

12.06.2017

B 1

some Message

12.06.2017

A 1

some Message

12.06.2017

C 0

some Message

## #

Here's is what i tried to do:

```
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("pathtologfile.log")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        Dim currentRow As String
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadLine
```

' this is my filter for todays date

```
                If currentRow Like ("*" & stringdate & "*") Then
                    timestamp = currentRow
                    'nächste Zeile
                    i = i + 1
```

'counting the rows to see the difference between a date and a "real" 1

```
                ElseIf currentRow Like "*1*" And i >= 2 Then
                    OutputTxT.AppendText(timestamp & " " & currentRow & (vbNewLine) & (vbNewLine))
                    'wenn in Zeile 2 dann +1 ansonsten zurück auf 1
                    If i <= 3 Then
                        i = i + 1
                    Else
                        i = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
              FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

So you see with that solution i only get the 1's that happened on a specific date. I like to have only the Letters that are currently 1.
I hope thats understandable :)
Would be nice if you can give me a hint on how to handle somthing like that :)

BEst Regards
Bernhard

Comment: Can you depend on the format of the text file? Three lines per Happening?

Comment: Hello! Yes its always three lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good! How about a little loop? I created a class so I could store the values in a simple List(Of T).

```
Public Class FileReading
    Private Sub ReadFile()
        Dim MyList As New List(Of LogHappening)
        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\testlog.txt")
        Dim line1 As String
        Dim line2 As String
        Dim line3 As String
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0 'Returns -1 if no more characters in file
            line1 = sr.ReadLine() 'Date
            line2 = sr.ReadLine() 'Letter & Number
            If line2.Trim.EndsWith("1") Then
                Dim initial As String = line2.Trim.Substring(0, 1)
                line3 = sr.ReadLine() 'message
                Dim Happening As New LogHappening(line1, initial, 1, line3)
                MyList.Add(Happening)
            Else
                line3 = sr.ReadLine()
            End If
        Loop
        sr.Close()
        For Each item In MyList
            Debug.Print($"{item.MyDate}, {item.Initial}, {item.Number}, {item.Message}")
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ReadFile()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class LogHappening
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(dteDate As String, strInitial As String, intNumber As Integer, strMessage As String)
        MyDate = dteDate
        Initial = strInitial
        Number = intNumber
        Message = strMessage
    End Sub

    Private _Date As String
    Public Property MyDate As String
        Get
            Return _Date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Date = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Initial As String
    Public Property Initial As String
        Get
            Return _Initial
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Initial = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Number As Integer
    Public Property Number As Integer
        Get
            Return _Number
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Number = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Message As String
    Public Property Message As String
        Get
            Return _Message
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Message = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helps alot. Now i just have to understand whats going on in there :)